# How to Create a Custom Event Handling class Like EventArgs

Tags: c#

how to write custom event handling classes, if any one having idea about how to create it or if you know any good article regarding this then please help me.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: There's a lot out there on google...this one looks pretty good and basic: http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-snippet-tutorial-custom-event-handlers

Comment: What's an "event handling class"?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean, but if you're talking about an EventArgs derived class:

```
public class MyEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    private string m_Data;
    public MyEventArgs(string _myData)
    {
        m_Data = _myData;
    } // eo ctor

    public string Data {get{return m_Data} }
} // eo class MyEventArgs


public delegate void MyEventDelegate(MyEventArgs _args);

public class MySource
{
    public void SomeFunction(string _data)
    {
        // raise event
        if(OnMyEvent != null) // might not have handlers!
            OnMyEvent(new MyEventArgs(_data));
    } // eo SomeFunction
    public event MyEventDelegate OnMyEvent;
} // eo class mySource
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 19):

I believe what you're referring to is a new EventHandler for an event, rather than an EventArgs. There are two easy ways of doing this. Firstly you can create an event that uses the generic EventHandler which is the quickest and easiest way of using a new EventArgs class:

```
event EventHandler<MyEventArgs> sampleEvent;
```

The second way is almost as simple, and probably neater from a syntax point of view, is to create a new delegate that has the arguments you want for your event which you can use straight away:

```
delegate void MyEventHandler(object sender, MyEventArgs e);
event MyEventHandler sampleEvent;
```

And this second method will allow you to reuse the handler later.

Comment: +1 for showing the EventHandler<MyEventArgs> way of declaring an event

Comment: Thanks for the generic Event handler solution. I was looking for a custom constructor on the EventHandler and didn't even consider that it was a generic class. Problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

You declare the event like this:

```
public delegate void MyEventDelegate(...);
public static event MyEventDelegate MyEvent = delegate { };
```

Then, to raise the event:

```
MyEvent(...);
```

The event is initialised to an anonymous delegate to remove the requirement to check for null each time you want to raise the event.